Is the protocol perfect zero knowledge?
Consider such protocol for $GI$ (Graph-isomorphism problem).
$P$ randomly chooses permutations $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, ..., \sigma_k$ and sends $H_1 = \sigma_1(G_0), ..., H_k = \sigma_n(G_0)\ (k > 1)$;
$V$ randomly chooses $b_1, ..., b_n \in \{0,1\}$ and sends it;
$P$ finds $\tau_i = \begin{cases}\sigma_i &\text{if } b_i = 0\\\sigma_i\pi&\text{if } b_i = 1 \end{cases}$ where $\pi(G_1) = G_0$ and sends $\tau_1,...,\tau_n$.
It is rather similar to classical one, showing $GI \in PZK$. The probability to accept non-isomorphic graphs seems to be not greater than $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^n}$ in this case. But would such protocol be zero-knowledge?

How does this differ from the classical protocol?  See, e.g., https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~abhishek/classes/CS600-442-Fall2016/S10.pdf.

@D.W. The difference is that P randomly chooses k permutations (I forgot to mention that k > 1). Whouldn't it give more information about isomorphism for verifier? I didn't manage to prove that protocol is zero-knowledge in the way it is done for classical one.

I think it would be helpful to [edit] your post to highlight that you are asking about whether you can run $n$ copies in parallel (concurrent self-composition), to make it clear what your focus is.

Zero-knowledge proofs do not in general compose in parallel. See this paper by Feige and Shamir for a (contrived) counterexample. Beyond this counterexample, there are several constraints to actually showing that a proof system composes in parallel. For example, Goldreich and Krawczyk prove that no 3-message proof system for a language $L$ can be black-box zero-knowledge, i.e. where the simulator only uses the malicious verifier as a black-box, unless $L\in BPP$. So the simulator would have to use the verifier in a non-black-box way. Non-black-box simulation has been used successfully to circumvent impossibility results, but the construction is rather more involved than the parallel repetition of a simple proof system.
